# The module to run \"java\" is not found among the available application modules

Tags: java, nginx, nginx-unit

When trying to PUT a Java application onto NGINX Unit it throws an error:

```
root@localhost:~# curl -X PUT -d@start.json '127.0.0.1:8443/config/'
{
        "error": "Invalid configuration.",
        "detail": "The module to run \"java\" is not found among the available application modules."
}
```

Using unit version 1.8.0

What could be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the JSC module must be installed separately:

```
# apt update
# apt install unit
# apt install unit-dev unit-go1.9 unit-go1.10 unit-jsc8 unit-jsc10 unit-php \
      unit-perl unit-python2.7 unit-python3.6 unit-ruby
```

After the installation, Java apps would be able to deploy.